# Trouble generating image of a JTable and its data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, paint

I'm having trouble using `paint()`. What I really want is to generate an image like this (it's a screenshot):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGXlg.png]

And what I get using the code above is this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vozpc.jpg]

The code for making images is this:

```
// EXTRA: generar una imagen con la factura:
public void GenerarImagenFactura(){
    File fichero = new File(FacturaCajeroGen.getFactura_ID() + ".jpg");
    String formato = "jpg";

    // Creamos la imagen para dibujar en ella.
    BufferedImage imagen = new BufferedImage(this.getContentPane().getWidth(),
                    this.getContentPane().getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    // Hacemos el dibujo
    Graphics g = imagen.getGraphics();
    this.getContentPane().paint(g);

    // Escribimos la imagen en el archivo.
    try {
        ImageIO.write(imagen, formato, fichero);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error de escritura");
    }
}
```

The rest of the code is this (the variable name of the JTable is `tbcarrito`):

```
public class GUI_Factura extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public static ControlMySQL DatosFacturaGen;
public static ResultSet aux;
Cliente ClienteCajeroGen;
Factura FacturaCajeroGen;
Personal CajeroGen;

public GUI_Factura(ControlMySQL DatosCajero, Cliente ClienteCajero, Factura FacturaCajero, Personal Cajero) {
    initComponents();
    DatosFacturaGen = DatosCajero;
    ClienteCajeroGen = ClienteCajero;
    FacturaCajeroGen = FacturaCajero;
    CajeroGen = Cajero;
    GenerarFactura();
}
    public void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI_Factura.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new GUI_Factura(DatosFacturaGen, ClienteCajeroGen, FacturaCajeroGen, CajeroGen).setVisible(true);
    });
}

public void GenerarFactura(){
    // Información de la Empresa:
    txtEmpresaNombre.setText("MegaMaxi el Condado");
    txtEmpresaCajero.setText(CajeroGen.getNombre() + " " + CajeroGen.getApellido());

    // Información de la Factura:
    txtFacturaID.setText(FacturaCajeroGen.getFactura_ID());
    txtFacturaFecha.setText(GenerarFecha());

    // Datos del Cliente:
    txtClienteNombre.setText(ClienteCajeroGen.getNombre() + " " + ClienteCajeroGen.getApellido());
    txtClienteCI.setText(ClienteCajeroGen.getCI());
    txtClienteDireccion.setText(ClienteCajeroGen.getDireccion());
    txtClienteTelefono.setText(ClienteCajeroGen.getNumero());

    // Generar el Carrito de Compras
    GenerarCarrito();

    // Generar Valores a Pagar
    txtSubtotal.setText(String.valueOf(FacturaCajeroGen.getSubtotal()));
    txtIVA.setText(String.valueOf(FacturaCajeroGen.getIVA()));
    txtDescuento.setText(String.valueOf(FacturaCajeroGen.getDescuento()));
    txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(FacturaCajeroGen.getTotal()));

    // Generar Imagen de la Factura
    GenerarImagenFactura();
}

public String GenerarFecha(){
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat hourdateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");
    return hourdateFormat.format(date);
}

public void GenerarCarrito(){
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tbCarrito.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    try {
        aux = DatosFacturaGen.consultarFacturaProductos(FacturaCajeroGen.getFactura_ID());
        while (aux.next())
        {
            model.addRow(new Object[]
            {aux.getString(1),aux.getString(2),aux.getString(3),
             aux.getString(4),aux.getString(5),aux.getString(6)});
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
}

// EXTRA: generar una imagen con la factura:
public void GenerarImagenFactura(){
    File fichero = new File(FacturaCajeroGen.getFactura_ID() + ".jpg");
    String formato = "jpg";

    // Creamos la imagen para dibujar en ella.
    BufferedImage imagen = new BufferedImage(this.getContentPane().getWidth(),
                    this.getContentPane().getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    // Hacemos el dibujo
    Graphics g = imagen.getGraphics();
    this.getContentPane().paint(g);

    // Escribimos la imagen en el archivo.
    try {
        ImageIO.write(imagen, formato, fichero);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error de escritura");
    }
}
```

Comment: A **very** quick shot: Change `this.getContentPane().paint(g);` to `this.getContentPane().print(g);`. When painting, double buffering may interfere with the painting process. Calling `print` will temporarily disable double buffering (and some more things). If this does not help, an [MCVE] would be great.

Answer (score 1):

First of all some Java programming basics:

1. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character
2. Method names should NOT start with an upper case character.

The forum uses keyword highlighting based on the above conventions and your variables and method are incorrectly being highlighted as class names making the code difficult to read.

Some Swing guidelines:

1. All updates to Swing components should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread. This would include the change of the LAF. Another test you can do is to just use the default LAF to see if there is any difference.
2. You are trying to create an image of the GUI before it is visible. It is possible that the state of all components has not been finalized before you create the image. A solution to this is to wrap your call to `GenerarImagenFactura()` in another `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` to make sure it executes at the end of the EDT.

You can also try using the [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class which provide methods for creating images of components.